# last child selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having a bit of an issue with last child. I have a dropdown nav and need to make the last dropdown align differently than the rest since the text is getting cut off.

My CSS for a normal dropdown looks like so:

```
.mainnav ul > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: -20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -transition: all 0.4s;
```

}

and when I adjust for the last dropdown I tried to use:

```
.mainnav ul > li > ul:last-child{
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: -120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -transition: all 0.4s; 
}
```

But when I put that in it effects all the dropdowns. You can see the test site here:
http://xeroproject.com/runa_tea/

I'm trying to adjust the IMPACT dropdown.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just tried and it didn't acknowledge the pseudo class at all.

Comment: Created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9h8m/ There are some styles missing because they are entered in the backend but it works enough to dig though it. I also put the two styles I tried to edit at the top of the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.mainnav ul > li > ul:last-child` selects all `<ul>` that's the last child of elements which match the selector.

For targeting the `<ul>` in last `<li>`

use

```
.mainnav ul > li:last-child > ul{
```

Instead of

```
.mainnav ul > li > ul:last-child{
```